# programatically scroll *within* a child div in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm writing my own directive which controls a child div (widget to be exact) within a larger screen.  The view for the directive contains a scroll bar, separate from the scroll bar on the larger webpage.

When a user clicks a button to calculate results I want to jump down to the results part of the view IFF results come back, but not move the screen if we don't get any results back for his query.

I'm having trouble doing this.  $anchorScroll doesn't seem to work, it scrolls the entire screen down instead of just the content of my directive's child div, and in fact doesn't scroll at all if the value I want to scroll to doesn't yet show on the child div.

I've seen plenty of examples of a directive that can be added to an HTML element to handle scrolling but they function on-click without the extra programmatic control I want, deciding when to actually scroll from within a controller method.  I don't know how to generalize this logic to work within my larger directive unfortunately.

How would I go about scrolling a child div programmatically *without* scrolling the larger div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `element.scrollTop = x`. You can see a basic demo [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqjEyL) - it will automatically scroll the child div's content after 2 seconds.

The demo uses `$timeout`, obviously you'll need to put that logic in your `$http` calls success part.

Assuming you have everything else done, the relevant part is the following:

```
var target =  angular.element(document.querySelector('#result'));
// #result is your directive's child div
target[0].scrollTop = 200;
// You'll have to calculate the exact number if it's not a fix one.
```